# Clone native js function

Tags: javascript

I saw another thread with a similar question, except window.alert turned out to not be a native function. This is what I want to do:

```
var byId = document.getElementById

document.getElementById = function(id){
    if(id == "some id"){
        //do stuff here
    }
    return byId(id);
}
```

Except byId is just a link to `document.getElementById` so when I change `document.getElementById`, calling `byId()` is just calling the new `document.getElementById`

Comment: smells like StackOverflow error. what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: In JS object referencing breaks if the original object gets reassigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood overriding function not working properly. When you assign the referenece of the function to `byId`, it loses its context. You need to pass the `document` as the context of the `byId` function via `byId.call(document, id)`.

```js
var byId = document.getElementById;

document.getElementById = function(id){
    if(id === "second"){
        console.log('Second found');
    }
    return byId.call(document, id);
}

document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = 'First changed !!!';
document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = 'Second changed !!!';
```

```html
<p id='first'>First</p>
<p id='second'>Second</p>
```